# HighCharts is conflicting with jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts, datepicker

I Had a working PHP page where the datepicker script from jquery would work with no issues. I decided to include HighCharts into the same page. As soon as I do, the datepicker stops working. If I remove highcharts the datepicker starts to work no issues. I tried putting noconflict for the datepicker and that did not work. Does anybody know how to have the jquery datepicker work with highcharts?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style/menustyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../scripts/datepicker/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="../../scripts/datepicker/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="../../scripts/datepicker/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style>
.auto-style1 {
 font-family: "Lucida Calligraphy";
 text-align:center;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#Date1" ).datepicker({
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true
 });
 });
 $(function() {
 $( "#Date2" ).datepicker({
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true
 });
 });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body style="color: #black; background-color: #0000FF;">
 <div align="center"id="MainWrapper" style="width: 90%">
 <div id="Maincontainer" style="width:100%">

<div id="PageHeader">
<?php include_once("../../template/template_header.php");?>
</div>

<div id="leftcolumn">
<?php include_once("../../template/menu.php"); ?>
</div>

<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:auto;width:70%;float:left;">
<h2 class="auto-style1">Call Exception Tracker - Reporting Portal</h2>

<form name="reportform" method="post">
  <table class="auto-style1" width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td style="height: 30px; width: 231px;" valign="bottom">From <input name="Date1" id="Date1" type="text" /></td>
  <td style="height: 30px; width: 193px" valign="bottom">to <input name="Date2" id="Date2" type="text" /></td>
 </td>

 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
 <br />
 <div id="container" align="center" width="99%">
<?php include_once("pie.php"); ?> //This is where HighCharts comes in
</div>

<div id="info"></div>
</div>
<div id="PageFooter">
<?php include_once("../../template/template_footer.php");?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Any errors on the javascript console?

Comment: @Mark The page does not show any errors...how can I see errors in the javascript console - how do I get to the console?

Comment: @Mark - I found the console on chrome. This is the error I am getting.   Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Comment: in both chrome and IE you press F12 and navigate to "Console".  Here's the most basic combination of highcharts and jquery-ui datepicker, I could code up real quick, it's working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/L4rYR/

Comment: @Mark - I see that the date picker is part of the same function...my datepicker is not for highcharts itself. Its for a form, wouldnt that not let the datepicker in the form itself stop working?

Comment: Same function?  They are just both in the same `.ready` handler that's all.  You need to spend some time attempting to recreate your problem in a simpler example (you've shown some code but a lot is hidden in php includes).  My fiddle shows no direct conflict between the two libraries.  If I had to take a wild guess why it's not working for you; I would guess you are inlining javascript or loading/reloading jquery in one of your includes.

Comment: @Mark - Hmm.. OK I will strip down my page and try it again. The includes are just HTML text so it would be the same across multiple pages. I will let you know if I find what is causing this.

Comment: @Mark - Ok, so you were right! Before like I have above the highcharts was in an include file. That contained the javascript part for highcharts. But when I put it all on the same page, it started to work. I think I am going to dump all the javascript into an external file to clean up the page a little. How do I accept your answer?!